# How to clone a WPF grid with all children?

Tags: wpf, xml, xaml, window, clone

I have several controls in my WPF window. I have divided the window into 4 sections. If I click on the section in the upper left, I want to copy the contents of this section in another window popup.
What I want to copy is a grid that can contain a lot of different controls, ex: togglebutton, button, panel... derived from ItemsControl, Control... and with DependencyProperty, ObservableCollection etc..

I tried :

- XamlWriter.Save(data);
- XamlServices.Save(data);

but I always have these errors :

> - Cannot serialize a generic type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1 or
> - A BadImageFormatException has been thrown while parsing the signature. This is likely due to lack of a generic context. Ensure
>     genericTypeArguments and genericMethodArguments are provided and
>     contain enough context.

Comment: Please provide more information e.g. some minimalist source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not clone XAML itself, this is brutal and wrong way.

Take a look at the possible [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) solution below. Let's say single DataGird represents a single business Item, so you need following:

- **ItemsWindow.xaml** - represents a ListView and single item of ListView is DataGrid representing an item details
- **ItemsViewModel** - expose list of Item objects (`ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }`)
- Each item of the ItemsWindow.ListView is represented by a DataTemplate like ItemDataTemplate
- ItemsViewModel exposed command `ICommand CopyItem` and in command handler actually copyiing only instance of the Item business entity and adding it to the `Items` list, WPF reflects this changes via bindings and UI will be updated by a new ListViewItem with a DataGrid representing a details of just copied Item

Useful links:

- [Model View ViewModel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) pattern
- [Commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921126%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx)
- [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) - short and clean overview of WPF data templates with examples